# Hazelcast Replicated Map: In-Memory-Format and Serialization

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm trying to check serialization/deserialization of objects in `Replicated Map` based on the `In-Memory-Format` config.

Based on the Hazelcast [docs](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#in-memory-format-on-replicated-map) for `In-Memory-Format`:

> OBJECT (default): The data is stored in deserialized form. This
> configuration is the default choice since the data replication is
> mostly used for high speed access. Please be aware that changing the
> values without a Map.put() is not reflected on the other members but
> is visible on the changing members for later value accesses.
>
> BINARY: The data is stored in serialized binary format and has to be
> deserialized on every request. This option offers higher encapsulation
> since changes to values are always discarded as long as the newly
> changed object is not explicitly Map.put() into the map again.

The sample immutable class and its custom-serializer:

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class MyObject {
    String str;
}
@Slf4j
class MyObjectSerializer implements ByteArraySerializer<MyObject> {
    private final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    public byte[] write(MyObject object) throws IOException {
        log.info("Serialize: {}", object);
        return jsonMapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
    }
    @Override
    public MyObject read(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        MyObject obj = jsonMapper.readValue(buffer, MyObject.class);
        log.info("Deserialize {}", obj);
        return obj;
    }
    @Override
    public int getTypeId() { return 1; }
    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

The `HazelcastInstance` configuration and creation (with the custom-serializer):

```
private static final HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config());

private static Config config() {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(new SerializerConfig()
            .setTypeClass(MyObject.class)
            .setImplementation(new MyObjectSerializer());
    return config;
}
```

The first test (`in-memory-format` is `object`):

```
@Test
public void test_put_inMemoryFormatIsObject() {
    ReplicatedMapConfig config = instance.getConfig().getReplicatedMapConfig("map1");
    config.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
    ReplicatedMap<Integer, MyObject> map = instance.getReplicatedMap("map1");
    map.put(1, new MyObject("Hi1"));
}
```

The output logs:

```
INFO HazelcastTest$MyObjectSerializer -| Serialize: HazelcastTest.MyObject(str=Hi1) 
INFO HazelcastTest$MyObjectSerializer -| Deserialize HazelcastTest.MyObject(str=Hi1)
```

The second test (`in-memory-format` is `binary`):

```
@Test
public void test_put_inMemoryFormatIsBinary() {
    ReplicatedMapConfig config = instance.getConfig().getReplicatedMapConfig("map2");
    config.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY);
    ReplicatedMap<Integer, MyObject> map = instance.getReplicatedMap("map2");
    map.put(2, new MyObject("Hi2"));
}
```

The output logs:

```
INFO HazelcastTest$MyObjectSerializer -| Serialize: HazelcastTest.MyObject(str=Hi2)
```

So the my issue is why in the `in-memory-format = object`, for each `map.put`, the object is serialized and deserialized once, while it's not necessary at all? i.e. the object can be put in the map without any serialization and deserialization.

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Note: The sample class is immutable and i'm not worried about modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast is a distributed data grid, so the assumption is data will be distributed across multiple nodes.  With an IMap, the data is partitioned so that each node holds a portion of the data; with a Replicated Map, each node will have a full copy.

Even if the object can be placed into the local map without serialization, the data will have to be serialized to send across the network to other nodes.

Are you running just a single node, or a multi-node cluster? I haven't checked the source code to see if we do any testing for the single-node case before serializing the data.

Comment: I want to decrease write time on current member (the replication in Replicated Map is asynchronous, and serialization should be done in another thread). I'm running in a multi-node cluster in production; but for showing the issue, i wrote these tests with a single node instance.

Comment: I looked at the code for ReplicatedMap.put and there isn't any code path that would allow you to bypass the serialization step.   The code that calculates the consistent hash, which tells us which partition to insert the object into, is based on the serialized key so having the key serialized is definitely needed up front.   I didn't dig into the code that sends to other partitions but bypassing the serialization doesn't appear possible.